# how to link between chrome extension and auth system built in django?

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension & I've made a log in and create a new account system using Django.
When users try to use the extension for the first time it will take them to the "Create new account" page, What I need to know is how to link between the extension & the Django authentication system in a way that it can always remember the user after signing up for the first time or logging in afterwards.
I know that I need to use API end point but if someone can give more detailed steps to do so will be much appreciated